# In Matlab, how do i drop na rows from a table?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

In Matlab, how do I drop rows with all NAs or with some NAs in the data.

I have a table with columns  `date open high low close volume`

The date exists in all the rows.

Some of the rows have all other columns besides the date with NA.

Some rows have all information ok except the close.

- How do I get a table without the "NA" rows (everything `NA` except the `date`)?
- How do I get a table with only the rows that `close` has data (a number)?
- How do I get a table with only the rows that `close` is a nonzero number.
- Conversly, how do I get a table with only the rows where everything is good except the `close` row having an NA?

I saw [this in Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/179142-how-can-i-remove-nan-values-from-a-matrix) for a matrix:

```
>> X = [10; 0.04500; 0; NaN; NaN];
>>X(isnan(X)) = []
ans = [10; 0,04500, 0]
```

[And this for all values being NAN](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68510-remove-rows-or-cols-whose-elements-are-all-nan) (which is never my case because the date 'index' column is always valid...)

```
A(~any(~isnan(A), 2),:)=[];
```

Which if I understand correctly means in pseudo code:

```
all in matrix A(hasno(numeric(A), INCOLUMNS), FORALLCOLUMNS) =? [];
```

Which results in all  rows WITH at least one numeric in one of the columns.

...But is there anything like it for a table, and for checking only the data fields?

Comment: I'm gonna try: `A(~all(~isnan(A(:,'open':)), 2),:)=[];`

Comment: I think the answer is in this documentation:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/clean-messy-and-missing-data-in-tables.html

Specifically, this function probably will help with the first problem:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmmissing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `Matlab R2016b` or greater, all you have to do in order to remove table rows with missing values is:

```
mytable = rmmissing(mytable);
```

and note that this also works with arrays as per [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmmissing.html):

> R = rmmissing(A) removes missing entries from an array or table. If A
>   is a vector, then rmmissing removes any entry that contains missing
>   data. If A is a matrix or table, then rmmissing removes any row that
>   contains missing data. Missing values are defined according to the
>   data type of A:
>
> NaN - double, single, duration, and calendarDuration
>
> NaT - datetime
>
> 'missing' - string
>
> 'undefined' - categorical
>
> ' ' - char
>
> {''} - cell of character arrays

If you are working with an earlier version, go for:

```
mytable = mytable(~any(ismissing(mytable),2),:);
```

A good multi-purpose tutorial to read on this argument can be found [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/clean-messy-and-missing-data-in-tables.html).